# can't get array to show items in new lines

Tags: php, arrays, printing

I have an array which I would like to show each item on a separate line.

when I echo $strError i get all the elements of the array but they are all inline as well as printing the tags.  What am I doing wrong?

```
$strError = 'Please check the following errors and try again:<ul>';
         foreach ($arrErrors as $error) {
                $strError .= '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
            }
        $strError .= '</ul>';
     }
```

Comment: just use a `<br>` tag

Comment: I tried using a <br> tag but it just printed the tag and didnt break the line.  Could you show me the corredt syntax for that?

Answer (score 0):

It is inline as you are using `.=` operator as it will concatenate it.

**error.php**

```
echo 'Please check the following errors and try again:<ul>';
foreach ($arrErrors as $error) {
         echo '<li>'.$error.'</li>';
 }
 echo '</ul>';
```

**HTML** where you are calling the result of `error.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = 'error.php';
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success:function(results)
    {   
       $('#concate').html(results);
    }
});
});
</script>
```

**HTML body**

```
<div id="concate"></div>
```

And the `HTML` that is returned by the `error.php` will be append inside the `concate div`
A simple example of what you need, hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for this.  I actually wanted to make a temporary variable as I need to use it on another page.  How can I do this?  Many thanks

Comment: You should use `ajax` for that, so you can just pass the `html`.